# Integral of Characteristic Function times measurable function is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

I want to verify my proof for the following problem:

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{S})$ and $f: X \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ is an $\mathcal{S}$ -measurable function. Define $v: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow[0, \infty]$ by
$$
v(A)=\int \chi_{A} f d \mu
$$
for $A \in \mathcal{S}$. Prove that $\nu$ is a measure on $(X, \mathcal{S})$.

**Attempt** The part that $v(\varnothing)=0$ is trivial. Given a countable union of disjoint sets $A=A_1\cup \ldots \cup A_n$, we know that any $x\in X$ can only belong to one $A_i$. Hence $\chi_A(x) = \chi_{A_1\cup \ldots \cup A_n}(x) = \chi_{A_1}(x) +\ldots +\chi_{A_n}(x)$. Plugging this into v:

$v(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)=v(A)  = \int \chi_A f d\mu  =\sum_{i=1}^n \int \chi_{A_i}fd\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n v(A_i) $

Comment: Your sum is finite, not countable, but the idea is right. For the sake of completeness, you might want to justify how you pull the sum out from under the integral.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks! Good point on the countable aspect. The reason we can swap the sum and integral is a consequence of the monotone converge theorem?